# Relationship between the textbox and image

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hey,
Easy question for ASP.NET profenssionals:
I have a few dynamic generated textboxes in a row. In this row is also a image with an eventhandler "onclick". I will create a relationship between the textbox and the image.
I click on the image, choose a value and then the textbox will be filled.

Currently my controls have following dynamic generated ID's:

**Button:**

```
ct100_cph_Detail_rpFields_ct109_rpCell_ct100_cbf_bed1_item_sym
```

**Textbox**

```
ct100_cph_Detail_rpFields_ct109_rpCell_ct100_tb_bed1
```

This two controls must be in a relationship. The best solution for me is with JavaScript, because I have not much ASP.NET skills..

Thanks for help ! :-)

Comment: Are you using pure JavaScript, or are you using a library like JQuery?

Comment: I can use both, but I have no skills in jQuery. Currently pure JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If the generated IDs always follow this scheme, you can access the textbox by getting the ID of the button/image, and replace the none-unique part inside this ID (_cbf_bed1_item_sym) with the none-unique part of the textbox-ID(_tb_bed1)

Example:

```
<input type="button"  value="click" 
   id="ct100_cph_Detail_rpFields_ct109_rpCell_ct100_cbf_bed1_item_sym" 
   onclick="document.getElementById(this.id.replace(/_cbf_bed1_item_sym$/,'_tb_bed1')).value='gotcha'"/>

<input type="text" 
   id="ct100_cph_Detail_rpFields_ct109_rpCell_ct100_tb_bed1"/>
```

There may be other ways, but to say anything about them you have to show the markup of such a row(needed to see what's the relation of these elements regarding to their position inside the document-tree)

Answer (score 0):

The "relationship" is the fact that they are both on the same row.

Serverside:

```
TableRow.Attributes.Add("onclick", "rowClick(event);")
```

Clientside:

```
function rowClick(e) {
    e = e || event;
    var target, img, textbox, row;
    target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName == 'IMG') {
        img = target;
        while(target.tagName != 'TR') {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        row = target;
        textbox = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        textbox.value = img.src;
    }
}
```